# Jedis with JOhm

Tags: redis, jedis

As per my understanding, with JOhm and Jedis, one could store/retrieve java class object in/from redis. One question I have is does JOhm also keep the java object in memory so that next time when that object (associated with key) is needed, it is returned from memory, instead of everytime reading from redis?

Answer (score 1):

No it doesn't keep anything in memory.
It will go to redis for basically everything you do.